# Do the Kwikspell courses work?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-theory

In Harry Potter we are introduced to Kwikspell course in The Chamber of Secrets (and never hear about it again).

We see Filch taking courses, presumably by mail.

The descriptions of Kwikspell make me think it is for people who are weak in magic (kind of like how Neville was supposed to be when he was younger), but had magic in them nonetheless.

However, Ron's comments later in the chapter make it sound like it is mainly for Squibs to learn magic.

However, it is strongly implied through out all the books that Squibs are essentially Muggles, and will never be able to do magic.

How then is a Kwikspell course supposed to work? Do we have any information to know if it works at all? Is it a scam?

An answer from [any level of canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117948/which-harry-potter-works-are-considered-canon/55370#55370) is welcome.

Comment: "Do we have any information to know if it works at all? Is it a scam?" Just in case we do not have any information about how it works, then we also must conclude that we don't know if it is a scam. Might be or might not be.

Comment: Kwikspell may be legit or borderline-legit, but I am morally certain that there are scams promising to grant magical power to Squibs.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Kwikspell courses are (probably) useful to some wizards, but not to squibs.

The Kwikspell course literature comes with two testimonials.

> **Madam Z. Nettles of Topsham writes:**
>   *‘I had no memory for incantations and my potions were a family joke! Now, after a Kwikspell course, I am the centre of attention at parties and friends beg for the recipe of my Scintillation Solution!’*
>    
>   **Warlock D. J. Prod of Didsbury says:**
>   *‘My wife used to sneer at my feeble charms but one month into your fabulous Kwikspell course I succeeded in turning her into a yak! Thank you, Kwikspell!’*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</sup></sub>

and states that they're useful for **witches and wizards** whose magical abilities are poor.

> Kwikspell is an all-new, fail-safe, quick-result, easy-learn course.
>   Hundreds of witches and wizards have benefited from the Kwikspell
>   method!”
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</sup></sub>

Interestingly, D. J. Prod appears to have gone from zero to hero with Kwikspell, having gone from 'feeble at charms' to [***warlock***](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Warlock). What we don't know is whether these testimonials are accurate, but it's notable that both quotes come from wizards with poor skills rather than (former) squibs.

Like most correspondence courses, they're probably most effective if you apply yourself and have some natural ability. JKR confirmed that Filch's course was utterly ineffective, but **that doesn't mean that it doesn't work for everyone, just that it didn't work for him** (presumably because no courses will help a squib to become magical).

> *Filch has carved himself a niche at Hogwarts and Arabella Figg
>   operates as Dumbledore’s liaison between the magical and Muggle
>   worlds. Neither of these characters can perform magic **(Filch’s
>   Kwikspell course never worked),** but they still function within the
>   wizarding world because they have access to certain magical objects
>   and creatures that can help them*
>
> <sub><sup>[J.K.Rowling Official Site -Extra Stuff SQUIBS](http://web.archive.org/web/20120208051328/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=19)</sup></sub>

It's also worth mentioning that **another of Kwikspell's courses** (*"[Wallop the Wombat Revision Course](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/wallop-the-wombat-revision-course/)"*) **is recommended by the Ministry of Magic itself** to those who fail to achieve a passing grade in their W.O.M.B.A.T. tests. It seems highly unlikely that the Ministry would suggest people take courses from a company that offers courses that are known to be worthless scams.

> (Do not be disheartened. You have only narrowly failed this most
>   demanding examination, and with a little further study would be sure
>   to pass. You are to be congratulated on a good attempt. We recommend a
>   crammer course of evening classes. Send an owl for full details of the
>   Wallop the Wombat Revision Course, available from the Kwikspell
>   Company.
>
> <sub><sup>[HP: Lexicon - WOMBAT Tests](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/w-o-m-b-a-t-tests/)</sup></sub>

Additionally, we have evidence (from JKR herself) that other *"correspondence courses"* *are* effective in teaching inexperienced wizards and witches.

> Occasionally, too, the magical community in a given country is tiny or far-flung and **correspondence courses have been found a more cost-effective means of educating the young.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Wizarding Schools - Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wizarding-schools)</sup></sub>

---

As to how the course actually functions, we learn in the Gameboy Colour game [*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Chamber_of_Secrets_(video_game)) that lesson #1 of the Kwikspell course (["*Learn Magic Fast with Kwikspell!*"](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Learn_Magic_Fast_with_Kwikspell)) covers

- **The appropriate way to hold your wand**
- **The incantation for the Skurge (scouring) charm.**

Which strongly suggests that the course comprises of *one basic wizarding technique* and *one spell* each lesson.

---

Comment: This is by far the best answer - there’s no textual evidence Kwikspell is a scam. The only one shown using one is Filch, who’s a Squib, and Squibs can’t learn magic through any method, so of course it won’t work. In addition, there’s nothing that suggests Kwikspell markets to Squibs.

Comment: @Bella Ron said Filch must have been a squib if he was taking a Kwikspell course, so I thought it was marketed in universe for squibs

Comment: @user13267 Kwikspell doesn’t seem to be marketed to Squibs, that’s just the reason why Ron thinks Filch is taking a Kwikspell course. Ron thinking that, or even that Filch is a Squib and tries their course, doesn’t necessarily mean that Kwikspell is actually meant for Squibs. The packaging and testimonials on Kwikspell itself indicates it’s for unskilled wizards, and *nothing* implies they themselves claim they can teach Squibs magic. Filch most likely wanted to take the course in the (misguided) hope he could coax some magic out of himself.

Comment: @user13267 Squibs also can’t attend Hogwarts because they aren’t magic, and Hogwarts can’t possibly teach them. However, Angus Buchanan, a Squib, and his family still try taking him to Hogwarts as an attempt to coax magic out of him, mentioned in the [JKR writing on Scottish rugby](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/scottish-rugby). *On the appointed day, his big brother Hamish took him to Hogwarts on the back of his broomstick, hoping against desperate hope that Angus would be allowed to stay once they got there, or that the school might be able to tease some magic out of him.*

Comment: "It seems highly unlikely that the Ministry would suggest people take courses from a company that offers courses that are known to be worthless scams." - you seem to have a higher regard for the competence and integrity of the MoM than the quality of their leadership (e.g. Cornelius Fudge, Rufus Scrimgeour, and Pius Thicknesse) indicates. By and large, the MoM appears to waffle between doddering folly and officious folly. I withhold comment on which is worse, or better.

Comment: @Valorum it’s not only Ron. Even Filch assumes that Harry has learned that Filch is a Squib, just be seeing the Kwikspell stuff.

Comment: Filch is the only one **at Hogwarts** taking Kwikspell courses. **At Hogwarts**, who else BUT a squib would try using the most basic of magic-learning resources *in secret*. The conclusion does seem foregone.

Comment: @Beanluc - Well, he could hardly sit in on classes can he? He's got a job to do.

Comment: "*What we don't know is whether these testimonials are accurate*" - if you believe those, I've got a couple of Nigerian princes I can put you in touch with.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I'm just mindful that the wizarding community is really quite small and these individuals are identified by both name and location. Fake testimonials would be far harder to pass off.

Answer (score 19):

As I read it, Kwikspell is a borderline scam.  It's on the same level as those ads you used to see in magazines, "Draw this [whatever]" to get you to send in for information on a correspondence art course.  The course, in the end, is unlikely to actually teach you anything you couldn't learn as well for less money from books found in art stores and libraries -- but it will give you a "certificate" when you finish.  The same is done for photography.

Sure, the MoM endorsed at least one of their courses, "Wallop the Wombat Revision Course" (thanks, Valorum, though I don't understand why anyone would want to wallop an innocent marsupial).  This might be because the Ministry was misled into thinking the courses worked, bribed to give an endorsement -- or perhaps they actually did work for people with magical ability (which doesn't include Filch, as far as we know).  The Kwikspell people surely didn't go out of their way to point out that a Squib wouldn't gain from sending them a lot of money.

In other words, Filch has been taken in by someone claiming they can teach magic to anyone, without even meeting them, for some number of knuts (or more likely galleons).  He's sending off his money and getting "lessons" by owl, and almost certainly gaining nothing from it, other than a misplaced confidence that he will, in time, be able to use magic.  We know he wasn't able to use magic, even up to the Battle of Hogwarts.

Comment: This seems extremely *opinion-based*. Can you offer any evidence to back up this bold assertion from the text, interviews, etc?

Comment: None whatsoever, other than that Filch was still non-functional in magic even in Herry's seventh year.

Comment: Filch was a squib he would probably be non functional in magic even when Harry's sons joined Hogwarts

Comment: Which makes him exactly the sort the Kwikspell scam would prey on.  Knows about magic, is around it every day, got none of his own.

Comment: The Ministry of Magic endorses at least one Kwikspell course (the "Wallop the Wombat Revision Course"). Would they recommend a company that sells scam courses?

Comment: In the days when Harry was in school, they might -- they were corrupted by Death Eaters, why not by ordinary bribery?

Comment: Ah, now you're indulging in fan-fiction to justify your answer though. Perhaps they'd been confunded to tell people it was good or had their memories altered (perhaps, perhaps)

Comment: Edited to reflect that we don't know why the Ministry would endorse the course -- scammers surely exist in the Potterverse (Lockhart surely wasn't the only one) -- and entertain the possibility that the only scam was failing to warn Squibs that it wouldn't help them.

Comment: @Valorum I find the idea that somebody in the Ministry of Magic had an ulterior motive to recommend a Kwikspell course more plausible than the idea that the witch and wizard who wrote the Kwikspell testimonials actually existed.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: And it is even more likely that the ministry of magic had no ulterior motive but had a number of incompetent employees, one of whom recommended the kwikspell course because, you know, connections... Don't we remember Mundungus and Fudge?

Answer (score 12):

The only person in the books that we see using Kwikspell is Filch, and it doesn't seem to have helped him. For instance, in *Order of the Phoenix* Filch we have the following:

> “Right you are, Headmistress!” wheezed Filch, who was a Squib and
>   could no more have Stunned the fireworks than swallowed them.

Apparently Filch was unable to do any magic at all despite the Kwikspell course.

However, it is unlikely that Kwikspell is meant for Squibs. It seems generally accepted that Squibs cannot gain the ability to do magic. For instance, we have Ron's comment in *Deathly Hallows*:

> "But how are they supposed to have 'stolen' magic?" said Ron. "It's
>   mental, if you could steal magic there wouldn't be any Squibs, would
>   there?"

The opening paragraph of the Kwikspell course indeed seems addressed to wizards who are poor at magic, not those who have no magic at all:

> *Feel out of step in the world of modern magic? Find yourself making
>   excuses not to perform simple spells? Ever been taunted for your
>   woeful wandwork?*

The testimonials as well reflect people who were able to do magic poorly, rather than not at all:

> *I had no memory for incantations and my potions were a family joke!*

> *My wife used to sneer at my feeble charms*

For such people it is certainly possible that Kwikspell would help. The first Kwikspell lesson is described as:

> "Lesson One: Holding Your Wand (Some Useful Tips)"

Not holding a wand properly could easily be something that would contribute to a wizard's poor performance of magic, and useful tips on how to hold a wand is something that could address that and be taught in a correspondence course.

Therefore, while it is certainly possible that it is a scam, we have no particular reason to think that Kwikspell wouldn't work **for those whom it was intended for**.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like these "learn a language in 3 weeks" ads. Whether these work as bold as they claim probably depends on the person's abilities (memory, languagy affinity) and time invested. They probably teach basic techniques that will give people a head start compared to other methods.
It sounds that kwickspell is comparable, given the quotes are true. Certain techniques help people to make progress like how to memorize things etc. 
"The appropriate way to hold your wand" seems one important basic technique that can make the difference - like they learn in Book1 about the important swish and flick for Wingardium leviosa. 
But it sound that it is made for wizards/witches poor at magic but not squibs. That's why it doesn't work for Filch (though he obviously still hopes that there is some magic in him - like Neville told that his family already thought he'd be a squib, Book1?)

Comment: The OP is asking for an answer from canon. This seems to be speculation.