# How do Muggleborns get their magic from Squibs?

Tags: harry-potter

Muggleborns are said to be distant descendants of Squibs who have married Muggles. But Squibs don't possess any magic to pass on to further generations. So how can Muggleborns get their magic from Squibs when Squibs themselves don't have any magical abilities?

Comment: "Squibs don't possess any magic" - Aside from being able to see magical creatures and ghosts?

Comment: **Katie Mosher:** *How exactly do muggleborns receive magical ability?
**J.K. Rowling:** *Muggle-borns will have a witch or wizard somewhere on their family tree, in some cases many, many generations back. The gene re-surfaces in some unexpected places.* - So, genetic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a Squib a Muggle?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/is-a-squib-a-muggle)

Comment: Because that's how genetics work. One can pass a genetic trait down to the next generations without possessing the said trait. Squibs keep the magic gene, it's just not active for some reason (maybe it's a recessive one), but they can pass it next.

Comment: Just because the answer is obvious, indeed the exact quote is already provided, doesn't mean the question deserves to be closed without an answer.  And word-of-god seems pretty clear-cut, so _not_ opinion-based.

Comment: @Valorum -- And apparently communicate with cats in addition to being to see or sense the presence of dementors. Despised and repressed as Squibs may be, I think there may be a lot more going on in that community than we've seen. In any event, since magic is genetic, and since it appears everywhere in the world, that means it's a common inheritance of the entire race, not really the province of a small group. It's  just that magic's phenotypical manifestation is what makes up the magical community at any given time. I wouldn't be surprised if there weren't different classes of Squibs...

Comment: ...as well. Recall that Mr Filtch was taking Kwikspell courses. Our focus in the Wizarding World is, of course, wizards. But there's a lot we don't know about magic, and a lot we don't know about Squibs.

Comment: @elemtilas Nope. Arabella Figg never saw the dementors, because squibs can't see them, since squibs lack magic. She lied in the Wizengamot Trial. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85969/can-squibs-see-dementors#:~:text=JK%20Rowling's%20website%20says%20this,her%20to%20see%20a%20Dementor.

Comment: @elemtilas Also, it is confirmed that Kwikspell course didn't work for Filch, and wouldn't work for any squib, because squibs don't have magic. Kwikspell was designed for wizards and witches with poor skill in magic. A squib isn't a wizard. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195548/do-the-kwikspell-courses-work